# restrict data types from user inputs in excel vba forms

Tags: excel, vba

how do I restrict users from inputting certain data types in text boxes...like in a text box meant for date how can I ensure user does not input invalid dates?

Comment: have you tried anything? via VBA? if so, post what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot restrict inputs to text boxes in for example the way you can restrict inputs to cells (via Data Validation). You need to trap an input via the Change or Exit event of the text box and validate the input type there. If it is an invalid input then set the textbox's Text property equal to "" (empty string) and display an alert.

Comment: Exactly what I thought to suggest) +1